# How can I use grpc's boringssl functionnalities to work with my nodejs program

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node, boringssl

I don't want to install another openssl when knowing Google gRPC has a working version of boringSSL.

Now, my challenge is to be able to access some functionalities such as calculate a salt and CMAC.

I am aware that Google does not promote the use of it in case something changes and breaks my code.

I saw there is file called 'binding.gyp' in the root of node_modules/grpc, but don't know if possible to use it.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several layers of problems with your question, and it's missing a lot of context, but here's a few things I can provide based on what I am getting:

First, grpc-node is deprecated, and you should move over to grpc-js, which is no longer containing native code.

Then, grpc-node doesn't actually use BoringSSL, it's in fact relying on nodejs exposing OpenSSL itself as a native API.

And finally, you're supposed to be able to use nodejs' exposed OpenSSL API in a native node module: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_linking_to_libraries_included_with_node_js